# Why is Toast notification using OnLaunched instead of OnActivated in windows 10 app?

Tags: azure, uwp, toast, azure-notificationhub

When clicking on my Toast notification the OnLaunched method is being called instead of the OnActivated.  And nothing is in the e.Arguments - any ideas?

My Toast template is the default Visual Studio Server Explorer template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<toast>
  <visual>
    <binding template="ToastText01">
      <text id="1">Test message</text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
</toast>
```

Answer (score 1):

`OnLaunched` is called because the legacy toast template is used:

> Note: If you are using the legacy toast templates from Windows 8.1, OnLaunched will be called instead.
>   [[docs]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast)

And `e.Arguments` is empty because the `launch` attribute of the `toast` is not set in XML ([see this MSDN page for details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868212.aspx)).

Comment: Reading the docs it seems indeed like the only explanation, but it still does seem weird that his event data is completely empty.

Comment: I see/saw that OnLaunched is called with a legacy template, however where/how do I send a "new" template?  I don't see how/what the XML format should be.   And as Andre B said the Arguments data shouldn't be empty with the legacy template...

Comment: See the [quickstart on sending a toast in UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast) to send a new ToastGeneric toast. Nothing is in e.Arguments because you didn't specify `<toast launch="myLaunchArgs">`

Answer (score 1):

It was so silly, so the default test toast created in Visual Studio has the template set as "ToastText01" but it should be "ToastGeneric"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<toast>
  <visual>
    <binding template="ToastGeneric">
      <text id="1">Test message</text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
</toast>
```